# How to pass data from a FSharp.Data.CsvProvider to a Deedle.Frame?

Tags: csv, f#, f#-data, deedle

I'm trying to pass data from a FSharp.Data.CsvProvider to a Deedle.Frame.

I'm almost new in F#, and I need to convert some CSV files from culture "it-IT" to "en-US", so I can use the data.

I found Deedle, and I want to learn how to use it, but I was not able to directly convert the data from a CSV file in Deedle (at least is what is printed in F# interactive).

I noticed that the CsvProvider makes the conversion, but after some days of attempts I am not able to pass the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that Deedle should be able to deal with CSV files that use non-US culture:

```
let frame = Frame.ReadCsv("C:\\test.csv", culture="it-IT")
```

That said, if you want to use the CSV type provider for some reason, you can use:

```
let cs = new CsvProvider<"C:/data/fb.csv">()

cs.Rows
|> Frame.ofRecords
|> Frame.indexColsWith cs.Headers.Value
```

This uses `Frame.ofRecords` which creates a data frame from any .NET collection and expands the properties of the objects as columns. The CSV provider represents data as tuples, so this does not name the headers correctly - but the `Frame.indexColsWith` function lets you name the headers explicity.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. In F# interactive, if I send the command: frame.Rows;; I have the values the same way as they are stored in the CSV file, I mean with decimal separator as "," instead of "." . Is it normal?

Comment: That sounds like the frame is loading the date as strings.. Does the CSV provider under the type to be float?

Comment: Yes, Tomas, it's right. In FSI, frame.Rows prints data as they are stored in the file. If I print the content of frame.Rows.Values I can see the values in the correct form. Thank you for your help.